# Unknown curly bracket in my Gatsby website

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

There is unknown curly bracket in my code but I cannot find it in any of the files. I use https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world/ as my starter library.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="note" content="environment=development" />
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="___gatsby"></div>
    <script src="/commons.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Take a look here:

[image]

Comment: Not sure what to suggest here other than going thru your code with a fine-tooth comb. You'd have to post the entire contents of your code in order to find it, and no one is going to sit here and go through it. Sorry if that sounds mean--I see you are a new user--but the main purpose of this site is to provide answers to questions which could help many people, and this just does not fall in that category.  EDIT: I am choosing to comment rather than simply downvote since that does not help to encourage better questions.

Comment: Thank you for this advise. After going thru my code, I found the curly bracket that I was looking. Your comment made me realise that I was asking a very stupid question. I will try my best to improve my question next time. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Nice work! Glad you were able to solve your issue. We'll be here next time you run into something a little trickier :)

Comment: Tip: It is good practice on StackOverflow for answering your own question and accepting it. You also get points for it.